# which python displays inconsistent paths

Tags: python, macos, path

My .zshrc file has the following path:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

But, after running `echo $PATH` I get the below output

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/anaconda3/envs/moby/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin
```

I don't know why the part with anaconda is at the end of $PATH

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What is your `if`  `then` part of code?

Comment: I have updated the prompt

Comment: So `export` command is executed only if `conda` exited with status `!=0` _and_ file `/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` does not exist. I'd recommend to run `.zshrc` manually either with `-x` or to put some debugging output to see what `PATH` is at each step of execution.